# How get item price without currency in osclass

Tags: php, osclass

How to get the item price without currency code in osclass? I need this value to send it to Paypal.

- with osc_item_formated_price() I get ex 10 USD
- with osc_item_price() I get 10000000

I want function to get 10 numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

osc_item_price() is the correct funtion to use but you have to divide the returned number by 1000000. You can use the following function to do so:

```
function getItemPrice() {
  return osc_item_price()/1000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is best solution

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please consider to mark this answer as accepted solution and maybe you like to vote it up.